# How do I earn crystals?

Tags: hero-siege

I have been playing Hero Siege for roughly two hours and my blue crystals are building up, but I don't understand how.

Is there anything specific that awards these crystals?

[image: Blue Crystals]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **First of all, You start off with 100 (it used to be 500, so this may vary as the game evolves) crystals when you buy the game.**

Also, it's good to understand that crystals are the only permanent currency featured in Hero-Siege. Gold is dropped upon death, but crystals will always be kept, until spent that is!

**After the start of the game, you can gain more crystals like this:**

> **1.** As a random drop from bosses. This is **very** rare, but every boss in the game has a slim chance of dropping some crystals.
>
> **2.** From achievements. Every achievement will award you with a specific amount of crystals. Easy achievements gives you a few crystals, while hard achievements often give you many more.
>
> **3.** From Crystals Chests. These chests are randomly found in-game, and you need a crystal key to open them. A crystal key can be bought with crystals, but it’s generally not a good idea to buy these keys to try to get more crystals (you will most likely lose-out in the long run).

Comment: I don't think people start with 100 crystals anymore. I bought the game on the last sale, and i have started with only 100 crystals.